# AEM: How to register a non-Sling Servlet?

Tags: jetty, osgi, aem, sling

I have to register a "org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.ProxyServlet" in AEM.

This helps in having a better development environment, where my project uses external REST API for transactional piece of project.

But using sling annotation (@SlingServlet) I could not able to do it.

Comment: I am not sure if that is easily doable. But may I ask why you want to do that? I have the feeling you are trying to solve a problem with this servlet because you know how it works but you did not find a AEM solution for the problem.

Comment: Did you try the [OSGI http whiteboard](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-http-service.html#using-the-osgi-http-whiteboard)?

Comment: @Abhishek Yes I tried "OSGI http whiteboard", but some how it did not seem to work in AEM.

Comment: @Jens In my set up, the front end connects to an external RESTfull service. For this to work, I need mod_proxy in Webserver. For development purpose, a proxy Servlet would serve that purpose.

Comment: @Dileepa pls add some code that you tried and error you got.

Comment: @Dileepa If I understand you right your "frontend" (I guess you mean your components with that) communicates with an external REST service. This seems to be happening in a Java class (maybe Model) and not Ajax. You now want to "proxy" all those REST calls through a servlet to return test data if you are in development? If so I would really strongly advise to not do that. You will have code in your application that is only meant for testing purposes. This is code that can introduce bugs etc. We always use external mocks for something like this. Create a REST mock and use it for testing.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend writing a sling servlet (One that extends from SlingAllMethodsServlet or SlingSafeMethodsServlet depending on requirements) and delegate control to your ProxyServlet. As the SlingHttpServletRequest and SlingHttpServletResponse are basically HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse.

This would mean you do not have to tweak anything on the AEM to make your servlet work at the same time gives you an sling context in your wrapper in case you might need in future.